# Upgrade PHP 5.2.x to PHP 5.4.15 - Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I know that there are some problems when upgrading to a new Zend Framework Version in combination with PHP Version. Like Zend Framework 2 needs PHP 5.3.

But does someone knows about problems with "old" Zend Framework Version like 1.5 and PHP 5.4 ?

I have Googled like hell but only found information about upgrading Zend Framework and which PHP version in minimum.

Would be nice to get some advice.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be fine, PHP is (largely) backward compatible. I would consider updating your ZF version though, 1.5 is pretty old.

Comment: Thanks i have just started to run PHPCodesniffer for unsupported PHP Functions against ZF 1.5.1 it seems it is *NOT* compatible.

Comment: Can you give some examples? And like I said, it'd be worth upgrading to 1.12.3 at the same time if you can (some minor changes might be required).

Comment: No important Problems: SQLITE dropped and used in Cache Backend SQLITE. set_magic_quotes_runtime in Zend_Cache_Backend_File. Action\Helper\Redirector.php , GOTO used. Sure Update to latest ZF is the goal :-)